# php mysql query string

Tags: php, mysql, string, search

I need help to query string from database please help.

```
<?php
$phone="8165526693@vtext.com";


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'toor');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('wizarddb')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Phone WHERE phone LIKE '%$phone%'"); 

if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($result(1); // outputs phone

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I have issues with echo or is the query wrong?

Comment: echo mysql_result($result(1); should be echo mysql_result($result(1));
(missing closing ')' )

Comment: is there any other error message that you are getting ?

Comment: what help do you need? Is there an error, something not working as you'd expect or it does nothing/white page?

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses, you should be getting a Parse Error. Or is that just a typo in the question, not the original code?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on the echo.

```
echo mysql_result($result(1); // outputs phone
```

That SHOULD be

```
echo mysql_result($result[1]); // outputs phone
```